# Is there a theory of generalized eigenvectors over commutative rings?

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Brown's Matrices over Commutative Rings book discusses the theory of eigenvalues, eigenvectors, and diagonalizing matrices over commutative rings, but unless I've missed something, nothing like [generalized eigenvectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector) is even mentioned. Has the notion of generalized eigenvectors ever been studied over commutative rings in any context more general than working over a field?

My interest stems from trying to find a closed form expression for the matrix exponential $e^{zA}$, where $z$ is an element of a finite dimensional real associative commutative algebra, and $A$ is a matrix built of elements of said algebra, which in the real case relies on the theory of generalized eigenvectors.

Comment: This post might help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88687/eigenvalues-for-matrices-over-general-rings

Comment: Dan Laksov and Anders Thorup have a series of papers on splitting algebras, some of which discuss applications to "diagonalizing" matrices over commutative rings. The following one is probably the most directly connected: Dan Laksov, *Diagonalization of matrices over rings*, Journal of Algebra, Volume 376, 15 February 2013, Pages 123--138, http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869312005601 .

Comment: [Frobenius normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form) seems like something worth looking into

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is how to compute the matrix exponential $\exp(a)$ where $a$ is an element of a finite-dimensional real associative algebra $A$. (Your phrasing is not more general: you're implicitly working in the algebra $M_n(A)$.) This reduces to the case of real matrices, because the left regular representation

$$A \ni a \mapsto \left( L_a : b \mapsto ab \right) \in \text{End}_{\mathbb{R}}(A) \cong M_{\dim A}(\mathbb{R})$$

is always faithful, and

$$L_{\exp(a)} = \exp(L_a).$$

So there's no need for a more general theory.